# Error Casting Spring's JndiObjectFactoryBean to ConnectionFactory for Solace-MQ JMS

Tags: jms, apache-camel, spring-jms, solace, solace-mq

I have a good working XML configuration for Camel Context that uses JNDI with Spring

Later Solace.JndiObjectFactoryBean gets used as connectionFactory

```
<bean id="Solace.JmsComponent" class="  on">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="Solace.JndiObjectFactoryBean" />
    <property name="destinationResolver" ref="Solace.JndiDestinationResolver" />
</bean>
```

I am trying to convert this into a Java class that extends from `org.apache.camel.spring.javaconfig.CamelConfiguration`. But there is one problem. When I try to set a connection factory on JMS component 
    component.setConnectionFactory(getJndiObjectFactoryBean()); getJndiObjectFactoryBean(), 
I get a compile time exception :

```
The method setConnectionFactory(ConnectionFactory) in the type JmsComponent 
is not applicable for the arguments (JndiObjectFactoryBean)
```

But when I try to cast JndiObjectFactoryBean returned from getJndiObjectFactoryBean explicitly to SolConnectionFactory, I get a runtime error

```
016-02-05 17:39:09,234|[localhost-startStop-1]|[]|[]|[ERROR] web.context.ContextLoader [line:307] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getJMSConfiguration' defined in class path resource [com//camel
/CamelRoutesConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org
.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration com.camel.CamelRoutesConfig.getJMSConfiguration()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean$$EnhancerByCG
LIB$$18b94f95 cannot be cast to com.solacesystems.jms.SolConnectionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsi
ngFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:581)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory
.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1029)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory
.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:925)
```

I believe do have have requisite jars in the class path. sol-common-x.y.z.jar, sol-jcsmp-x.y.z.jar, sol-jms-x.y.z.jar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `JndiObjectFactoryBean` cannot be casted into a `ConnectionFactory`.

There are two options:

1. Use `JndiObjectFactoryBean.getObject()` in the `JndiObjectFactoryBean` that's returned by your `getJndiObjectFactoryBean()` method.
2. Get Spring to provide the `ConnectionFactory`.

   `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("config.xml");
   ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) context.getBean("Solace.JndiObjectFactoryBean");`

Comment: Hi Russell , I am not able to get it working , though I used getObject(). Could you please provide any sample code.

Answer (score 1):

We faced a simular situation when porting a working Spring XML configuration (used by Apache Camel to read from a Weblogic JMS Server queue) to a Spring-Boot favoured Java configuration.

```
jmsConfiguration.setConnectionFactory( (javax.jms.ConnectionFactory)getJndiFactoryBean().getObject());
```

Above code did the trick to emulate

```
<bean id="jmsConfiguration" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jndiFactoryBean"/>
    <property name="destinationResolver" ref="jndiDestinationResolver"/>
</bean>
```

(Unclear what Spring XML does extra under the cover though, since it's not as simple as setting the `jndiFactoryBean` on the `jmsConfiguration`)

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using the getObject() approach make sure you call afterPropertiesSet() before you use getObject()

```
org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean cf = new org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean();
JndiTemplate jndiTemplate = new org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate();
Properties environment = new Properties();
environment.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.xxx"); //initial context
environment.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url", "xxx://xxx"); //url
jndiTemplate.setEnvironment(environment);
cf.setJndiTemplate(jndiTemplate);
cf.setJndiName("XXX");
//System.out.println(cf.getObject()); //null
cf.afterPropertiesSet();
//System.out.println(cf.getObject()); //now has the value

org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter adapter = new org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter();
adapter.setTargetConnectionFactory((ConnectionFactory) cf.getObject());
```