# why use JndiObjectFactoryBean to config JNDI datasource did not work?

Tags: java, spring, jndi

when I uss  Java-base to config my JNDI. Spring 4.2.5.

But If I use JndiObjectFactoryBean to config.when I want to get the `datasource`,the object will be null.

```
@Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        JndiObjectFactoryBean jndiObjectFactoryBean =new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
        jndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiName("jdbc/SpittrDS");
        jndiObjectFactoryBean.setResourceRef(true);
        jndiObjectFactoryBean.setProxyInterface(DataSource.class);
        return (DataSource) jndiObjectFactoryBean.getObject();  //NULL!!!
    }
```

But if change the method to this,it work well.

```
@Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        final JndiDataSourceLookup dsLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        dsLookup.setResourceRef(true);
        DataSource dataSource = dsLookup.getDataSource("java:comp/env/jdbc/SpittrDS");
        return dataSource;
    }
```

I do not know where is the problem.

Tomcat 9.0  context.xml

```
<Context>

    <!-- Default set of monitored resources. If one of these changes, the    -->
    <!-- web application will be reloaded.                                   -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
    <!--
    <Manager pathname="" />
    -->

    <Resource name="jdbc/SpittrDS"
      auth="Container"
      type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
      url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spittrds"
      username="root"
      password="1"
      maxActive="100"
      maxIdle="20"
      minIdle="5"
      maxWait="10000"/>
</Context>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The actual lookup in JndiObjectFactoryBean is done in the lifecycle callback method. Either call the method explictly in your @Bean method like this (workaround)

```
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        JndiObjectFactoryBean jndiObjectFactoryBean =new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
        jndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiName("jdbc/SpittrDS");
        jndiObjectFactoryBean.setResourceRef(true);
        jndiObjectFactoryBean.setProxyInterface(DataSource.class);
        jndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return (DataSource) jndiObjectFactoryBean.getObject();  //NULL!!!
    }
```

Or the better approach. Let your @Bean method return the JndiObjectFactoryBean and manage its lifecyle. Then in your dependent beans that require a DataSource inject the datasource created from the factory

```
    @Bean
    public JndiObjectFactoryBean dataSource(){
        JndiObjectFactoryBean jndiObjectFactoryBean =new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
        jndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiName("jdbc/SpittrDS");
        jndiObjectFactoryBean.setResourceRef(true);
        jndiObjectFactoryBean.setProxyInterface(DataSource.class);
        return jndiObjectFactoryBean;
    }

//in your dependnecy

@Bean
public SomeBean someBean(DataSource dataSource){
   //use the injected datasource shich comes from the factory
}
```

Comment: I want to know why this method `jndiObjectFactoryBean.getObject()` return `null`

Comment: As i said the actual lookup is done in the afterPropertiesSet method which Spring calls after the bean has been created. Before that call the object wont have been retrieved from JNDI.

Comment: If I have multiple Data sources, then how to select specific one in someBean() ?

Comment: check out also here for people struggling with Spring trying to initialize data sources too early, when they cannot yet be looked up via JNDI (it seems) - i couldn't get this to work, but it seems warmer there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32776410/configure-multiple-datasource-in-spring-boot-with-jndi

Answer (score 1):

I landed here without realizing this was a problem I had faced in the past - [Error Casting Spring's JndiObjectFactoryBean to ConnectionFactory for Solace-MQ JMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35298732/error-casting-springs-jndiobjectfactorybean-to-connectionfactory-for-solace-mq/40295451#40295451)

So a workaround (not the preferred way) is to call afterPropertiesSet() on jndiObjectFactoryBean before attempting to getObject()

```
@Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        JndiObjectFactoryBean jndiObjectFactoryBean =new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
        jndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiName("jdbc/SpittrDS");
        jndiObjectFactoryBean.setResourceRef(true);
        jndiObjectFactoryBean.setProxyInterface(DataSource.class);
        jndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return (DataSource) jndiObjectFactoryBean.getObject();  //NOT NULL
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For those just looking for a way to define a datasource via JNDI, I would go for:

```
@Bean
public JndiObjectFactoryBean dataSource(){
    return new JndiDataSourceLookup().getDataSource("jdbc/SpittrDS");
}
```